# lambda expression to get the count of desired values

Tags: lambda, java-8

I have a `List<String>` which is like,

```
List<String> dummyList=Arrays.asList("a","b","c","a","b","e","f","e");
```

I have a list which contains names of students in a class, I need a lambda expression to fetch only the count of students with names "a","b","c".

I tried using,

```
dummyList.stream().collect(Collectors.groupingBy(Function.identity(), Collectors.counting()));
```

it gave count of entire students in the class, but I need the count of students "a","b","c", the final map should be of,

```
a:2
b:2
c:1
```

Comment: Look at the Java 8 solution there; you want to `filter`. In this case `.filter(s -> s.equals("a") || s.equals("b") || s.equals("c"))`

Comment: Use a `Predicate` to **filter** the stream: `Set<Character> whitelist = Stream.of('a', 'b', 'c').collect(Collectors.toSet()); Predicate<String> condition = s -> s.length() > 0 && whitelist.contains(s.charAt(0));`